# Unity editor crashes when opening project, with no error in Editor.log

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash, crash-reports, unity-editor

My Unity Editor crashes on every project, even newly created ones.

I have tried multiple solutions, including reinstalling Unity Hub, reinstalling Unity Editor, changing Unity Editor Version to latest, chaning Unity Hub to 2.5, and so on. I have also tried to disable my NVIDIA graphic card and use AMD instead. None of these helps. And no error log showed in Editor.log. The Editor.log is attached, you can preview it in the following image. During those attempts, I noticed the following details:

The startup screen stuck for a while and then disappears on "Initialize Graphic" or "Initializ Scripting". If it is a new project, it disappears on "Initializ Scripting", while if it is a existing project, it disappears on "Initialize Graphic". Notice that when the screen stuck there, the timer stops ticking. See Screenshot: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgOax.jpg). The screen disappears exactly after the state showed in the screenshot.

The log stopped on "Initialize mono ... Mono config path ...". Here is a preview of Editor.log: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w38QB.jpg. The full version is at [Editor.log File.](https://cd-1302933783.cos.ap-guangzhou.myqcloud.com/Editor.log)

**Basic Info**

- OS: Windows 11 22000.856 (Lenovo Laptop);
- Processor: AMD Ryzen 7 5800H with Radeon Graphics;
- Graphic Card: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060;
- Graphic Card Driver: 32.0.15.1694; NVIDIA Studio 516.94;
- DirectX 12, all enabled; Driect3D DDI: 12;

**Update:** I have tried copying Unity from other normal computer, using a flashdrive. And the copied Unity, which is OK on other computer, crashes on my computer.

**Update:** I have tried installing the same version of Graphic driver on another computer and try to run Unity on that computer, it runs normal. That maybe means that the problem is not about the Graphic driver. My problem remains unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

Before opening project:
Go to your project folder > Packages > manifest.json and remove  [com.unity.render-pipelines.universial@12.1.7]
Do the same in packages-lock.js

Comment: I noticed that the URP-related error is just a small problem. On a new project created from template, there is no such issue. It just simply stuck at "Initialize Graphic" step and then silently disappear.

Answer (score 0):

did you ever solve this problem? im getting the exact same thing on my computer atm. the only difference is it works for a couple of days before it dies (i fixed it once by doing a full system reset but don't feel like doing that every time it dies.)

Comment: figured it out. if you go into your program files >unity and you delete your license it should open fine again. (program files is a hidden file)

Answer (score 0):

I found the perfect solution to it, just change the name of the scene you are opening in Unity, then directly start that scene.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue with the editor permanently hanging on "Initialize Scripting" and the problem wound up being related to some new cache server settings that had gotten changed when I was trying to get Unity Accelerator to work. My solution was to revert the changes that had been made to the /ProjectSettings/EditorSettings.asset file, which basically set the m_CacheServerMode line to equal 0, and removed the IP and port for the m_CacheServerEndpoint line. It also removed the following lines entirely:

m_CacheServerEnableAuth: 1
m_CacheServerEnableTls: 1
m_CacheServerDownloadBatchSize: 128
m_CachingShaderPreprocessor: 1
m_PrefabModeAllowAutoSave: 1

Hope that helps!